# Argo CD - Can't Login To UI After SSO Login

Tags: single-sign-on, argocd, openid-dex

I setup the Dex Github connector and can login successfully.

This is from the Dex server logs.
`msg="login successful: connector \"github\"`

This is from the argocd server logs.

```
│ time="2023-03-07T14:09:52Z" level=info msg="Initializing OIDC provider (issuer: https://argocd.dev.xxx.com/api/dex)"                                                          │
│ time="2023-03-07T14:09:52Z" level=info msg="received unary call /session.SessionService/GetUserInfo" grpc.method=GetUserInfo grpc.request.content= grpc.service=session.SessionSer │
│ vice grpc.start_time="2023-03-07T14:09:52Z" span.kind=server system=grpc                                                                                                           │
│ time="2023-03-07T14:09:52Z" level=info msg="finished unary call with code OK" grpc.code=OK grpc.method=GetUserInfo grpc.service=session.SessionService grpc.start_time="2023-03-07 │
│ T14:09:52Z" grpc.time_ms=8.645 span.kind=server system=grpc
```

However, after login the screen blinks and I am back to the login page.

This is my RBAC setup.

```
configs:
  cm:
    accounts.xxx-admin: apiKey, login
    accounts.xxx-developer: apiKey, login
    url: "https://argocd.dev.xxx.com"
    dex.config: |
      connectors:
        - type: github
          id: github
          name: GitHub
          config:
            clientID: $dex.github.clientID:dex.github.clientID
            clientSecret: $dex.github.clientsecret:dex.github.clientSecret
            orgs:
            - name: xxxorg
  rbac:
    create: true
    policy.default: role:none
    policy.csv: |
      p, role:none, *, *, */*, deny
      p, role:xxxadmin, applications, *, */*, allow
      p, role:xxxadmin, clusters, get, *, allow
      p, role:xxxadmin, repositories, get, *, allow
      p, role:xxxadmin, repositories, create, *, allow
      p, role:xxxadmin, repositories, update, *, allow
      p, role:xxxadmin, repositories, delete, *, allow
      g, xxx-admin, role:admin
      g, xxx-developer, role:readonly
      g, xxxorg:devops, role:admin
      g, xxxorg:engineering, role:admin
      g, xxxorg:app, role:readonly
      g, xxxorg:automation, role:readonly
      g, xxxorg:automation-qa, role:readonly
      g, xxxorg:de, role:readonly
```

Comment: Can you share the logs for the argocd-dex-server Pod? Maybe this https://medium.com/cloud-native-daily/argo-cd-and-octocat-together-again-for-a-good-reason-enable-sso-in-kubernetes-1e3f0c9959db can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Try restarting argocd-server pod

Answer (score 0):

In my case, deleting cookies from my browser did the trick.